# rails 4 mocking session in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'mysql2
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment",__FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require "capybara/rspec"
include Capybara::DSL

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

**spec/support/controller_macros.rb**

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      # user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end

  def load_key
    session[:master_key] = SecureRandom.hex(24)
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/factory.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "test@test.com"
    password "12345678"
  end
end
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :load_key!

  def index
    @categories = Category.where("user_id is null or user_id = ?", current_user).order(updated_at: :desc)
  end
  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

**spec/controllers/categories_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe CategoriesController do
    login_user
    load_key

    it "get list of categories" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def load_key!
        redirect_to(key_path) unless session[:master_key]  
    end
end
```

I would like to bypass a **load_key!** before_filer in CategoriesController. I added method `load_key` to controller_macros.rb. But it gives me the error:

**undefined local variable or method 'session' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::CategoriesController:Class (NameError) from d:/sites/key_manager/spec/support/controller_macros.rb:19:in `load_key'**

Looks like `session` variable is unavailable under rspec.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was a quite simple.
I should use `request.session` rather than `session`.
In this case I should transfer a session variable assign from `controller_macros.rb` to `categories_controller_spec.rb`:

**categories_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

describe CategoriesController, :type => :controller do
    login_user

    it "redirect to key form when key was't loaded" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to redirect_to(key_path)
    end

    it "view password list #index" do
      request.session[:master_key] = SecureRandom.hex(24) # <======================

      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end
end
```

**controller_macros.rb**

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin) # Using factory girl as an example
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      # user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: does not look simple to me!